# How long is the user token for BigQuery using SIMBA ODBC driver valid?

Tags: google-bigquery, simba

We are connecting to Google BigQuery using SIMBA ODBC driver, and using user authentication while connecting. There is a key token which is generated for the connection. For how long is this key token valid? When would it expire?

Answer (score 1):

Based on this doc:

http://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/mac/content/odbc/bq/features/authentication.htm

I think you are using a refresh token. The refresh token is used to get a new access token and refresh it when the access token expires. I believe the a refresh token does not expire:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35465423/6896033

Here is more info about the refresh token:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2